# exporting to excel with lists stored in db

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel

Trying to export product date to excel. The description for product is stored in db with `<ul><li>` tags.

Here is the code for exporting to excel

```
<?php
//fetch query 

    $header .= "Product Code \t";
    $header .= "Product Name \t";
    $header .= "Description \t";
    $header .= "Purchase Cost \t";
    $header .= "Selling Cost \t";
    $header .= "Type \t";
while($rowtt = mysqli_fetch_array($queryrr))
    {
         $line = '';
         $code = $rowtt['code'];
         $name = $rowtt['Pname'];
         $descr = strip_tags($rowtt['description']);
         $pcost= $rowtt['pcost']; 
         $scost = $rowtt['scost'];
         $type= $rowtt['type'];

        $line .= $code."\t";
        $line .= $name."\t";
        $line .= $descr."\t";
        $line .= $pcost."\t";
        $line .= $scost."\t";
        $line .= $type."\t";
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );
  }

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}  

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Products.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

print "$header\n ".$data."";
```

Getting exported to excel, but in description it has li tags like this
`<ul>
<li>Lorel ipsum 123 </li>
<li>Lorel ipsum 123 </li>
<li>Lorel ipsum 123  </li>
<li>Lorel ipsum 123 </li>
</ul>`

But it is displaying like this

`Product Code | Product Name | Description     | Purchase Cost | Selling Cost |Type
PT001        | ABCD         | Lorel ipsum 123

                              Lorel ipsum 123
                              Lorel ipsum 123
                              Lorel ipsum 123

                                                 1500         | 1800         | Type1`